# automapper working with attributes c#

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two objects, I want to map them using AutoMapper Attributes, these are my target objects:

```
public class ClaseB
{
    public string UBLVersionID_nuevo { get; set; }

    public ClaseB_inside objetoB_inside { get; set; }
}

public class ClaseB_inside
{
    public string texto_inside { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my source class:

```
[MapsTo(typeof(ClaseB))]
public class ClaseA
{
    [MapsToProperty(typeof(ClaseB), "objetoB_inside.texto_inside")]
    public string texto { get; set; } = "texto prueba";

    [MapsToProperty(typeof(ClaseB), "UBLVersionID_nuevo")]
    public string texto2 { get; set; } = "texto 2 de prueba";
}
```

when I try to map I get the following error:

> Error mapping types

and with this change:

```
[MapsTo(typeof(ClaseB))]
public class ClaseA
{
    [MapsToProperty(typeof(ClaseB_inside), "objetoB_inside.texto_inside")]
    public string texto { get; set; } = "texto prueba";

    [MapsToProperty(typeof(ClaseB), "UBLVersionID_nuevo")]
    public string texto2 { get; set; } = "texto 2 de prueba";
}
```

I get `null` in `ClaseB.objetoB_inside`  but `ClaseB.UBLVersionID_nuevo` it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the way you are defining the mapping.  Consider the following if you weren't using Automapper attributes and was initializing through the static API:

```
        Mapper.Initialize(expression =>
        {
            expression.CreateMap<ClaseA, ClaseB>()
                .ForMember(
                    from => from.objetoB_inside.texto_inside, 
                    to => to.MapFrom(a => a.texto2));
        });
```

This mapping would result in the following exception:
`Expression 'from => from.objetoB_inside.texto_inside' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.`

And I think that's the same issue with the Attributes definition.

So I would suggest implementing the following:

```
public class MapsToClaseB : MapsToAttribute
{
    public MapsToClaseB() : base(typeof(ClaseB)) { }

    public void ConfigureMapping(IMappingExpression<ClaseA, ClaseB> mappingExpression)
    {
        mappingExpression.AfterMap(
            (a, b) => b.objetoB_inside = new ClaseB_inside{texto_inside = a.texto});
    }
}
```

You just then need to decorate your class with this:

`[MapsToClaseB]`